# JavaFX DatePicker set alignment of date value

Tags: java, css, javafx, datepicker, javafx-8

When I use the `Datepicker` of JavaFX and use the full width of the node, the text of the date picker is not centered.

I tried with `setStyle("-fx-alignment: center;")` but this does not work.

[image]

I want something like this (made with paint):

[image]

How can I center the text? Here is the examplecode:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class JavaFxExample extends Application {

    private BorderPane borderPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        borderPane = new BorderPane();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(borderPane, 600, 400));
        stage.show();
        running();
    }

    private void running() {
        DatePicker datepicker = new DatePicker();
        datepicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());
        datepicker.setStyle("-fx-alignment: center;"); // this does not work :(
        datepicker.setPrefWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        borderPane.setCenter(datepicker);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the following CSS (in a stylesheet file):

```
.date-picker > .text-field  {
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old but instead of a css file the easier method that I use is as following:

```
 datepicker.getEditor().setStyle("-fx-alignment: center;");
```